# App does not properly validate SSL certificates - Ionic Android

Tags: android, security, ssl, ionic-framework, burp

On our Ionic application, we have actually implemented SSL pinning using advancedHttpPlugin but still, the security team was able to use a third party tool Burp Suite to install a CA in the mobile and track the application, please find the message given for fixing it below:

> Secure Socket Layers (SSL), or Transport Layer Security (TLS) in its
> more modern implementation, are protocols designed to provide security
> for network communication by means of encryption. This protocol is
> most commonly associated with other protocols to provide a secure
> implementation of the service that protocol provides. Certificate
> pinning is the process of associating the backend server with a
> particular X.509 certificate or public key instead of accepting any
> certificate signed by a trusted certificate authority. After storing
> ("pinning") the server certificate or public key, the mobile app will
> subsequently connect to the known server only. Withdrawing trust from
> external certificate authorities reduces the attack surface (after
> all, there are many cases of certificate authorities that have been
> compromised or tricked into issuing certificates to impostors). a) In
> order to make your communication safer, explicitly compare the SSL
> certificate used for the connection with an expected client-side
> certificate.

On Ionic, is there any other method we need to include to also restrict Burp CA.

Comment: Instead of applying a plugin you should just use the Android way: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CertificatePinning

Comment: Hi @Vinu V, i am also facing same issue, please let me know the solution you applied. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Laxman, no we are yet to resolve the issue. We talked with the security team and considering we already have SSL pinning, they reduced criticality to LOW.